# ST_Transform doesn't work in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, database

When i run the query with `ST_Tranform` I get this error:

> Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID
>   SQL state: XX000

How can I resolve this error? I want to convert from UTM into geographic lat/lon.

This is the query that gives me the error:

```
select st_asgeojson(st_transform(geom, 4326)) AS geojson FROM ptable where level_1='Built Up'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select st_asgeojson(st_transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, XXXX), 4326)) AS geojson FROM  ptable where level_1='Built Up'
```

Try setting SRID beforehand by replacing `XXXX` with the code of your SRID.

Comment: i didn't get you.how to do setting of SRID

Comment: It is there, look at `ST_SetSRID(geom, XXXX`. Perhaps you should read also http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_SetSRID.html.

Comment: @user30184 yah i have set that SRID and st_tranform start working but its not converting UTM into LATLONG

Comment: Give me coordinates of one point and the EPSG code of your UTM projection and I can have a try.

Comment: @user30184 These are the coordinates I'm getting Or you can check this link plnkr.co/edit/YEG6vCA8yvi3KNzVt2W6?p=preview in which there is one file which is Multipolygon.geojson So this is the output am getting through that query which is not in LATLONG form

Comment: UPDATE mytable SET geom  = ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326); And this the way i have set my SRID. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on what crs your coordinates are in. If they're in EPSG:4326, it's gonna work, you'll need to use st_transform otherwise though.

Comment: @MichalZimmermann yah they are in EPSG: 4326 as you said i have updated SRID .after running that query it stop giving the error of st_transform. But the main problem is still remain unable to convert UTM to LATLONG

Comment: Do you have any idea about the coordinate system of your data? You say they are in UTM but which zone?

Comment: @user30184 WGS 84 UTM zone .

Comment: There are many UTM WGS 84 zones http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm.

Comment: GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]] see this the info i got it through geoserver is this helpful to solve my problem

Comment: That definition does not suit at all with coordinates 309556.45310621,2325477.63795461. Where did you get the source data? Can you ask from the provided in which the projection the data are? You simply must know the original coordinate system and have it right before you can do any coordinate transformations.

Comment: @user30184  its working now because uploading file in postgreSql was wrong . I have del the file did it again  .Thank you So much both of you. :)

Answer (score 2):

when you import shape file to PostGIS, did you set SRID?

[image]

My example is srid=2230, the default is 0, you must manually type in. The postgis import manager did NOT recognize the esri xxx.prj file, which has projection info, if you open that file, you can NOT see srid=2230. 
There are 2 ways you can get srid= 2230.

1) go to http://prj2epsg.org/search , upload your xxx.prj file, it will search for it and show you result 2230.

2)Or you can use arcCatalog, right click shape file, choose properties,
you can find WKID:2230

[image]

If you failed to manually set SRID, while import, no worry,

you can use sql to update SRID. By doing this, you set all geometry in this table srid=2230.

Note: no actual coordinate transformation occur, only update the metadata about SRID to 2230, default is 0.

For my case, I excute SQL:

```
   SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('city_parks','geom',2230);
```

Finally, your geometry table has SRID=2230 
Now you can output geojson to SRID=4326 by doing this:

```
   select st_asgeojson(st_transform(geom,4326)) from city_parks;
```

This is give you correct lat, long coordinate which you can put on any web map, google, bing, leaflet, openlayers...etc...

Previous solution also work, because st_setsrid will literally update each of your geometry srid to 2230.

```
     select st_asgeojson(st_transform(st_setsrid(geom,2230),4326)) from city_parks;
```

Summary:
          You should manually set SRID while you import shape file, (in future, I hope POSTGIS import tool should automatically read esri's xxx.prj file and automatically popup the 2230 for me).

```
      If you forget to set SRID while import, you can always update your table's SRID metadata by SQL : 

            SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('city_parks','geom',2230);
```

When you table's SRID is set correctly, you will be able to export to geojson by transform to SRID=4326.