# st_transform does not work

Tags: transform, st

I am trying to transform a geometry from srid 4326 to 26915.

> SELECT
> ST_Transform(s.geompos, 26915)
> FROM sites s

But i got error :

ERROR:  could not form projection (LWPROJ) from 'srid=4326' to 'srid=26915'
SQL state: XX000

I am on ubuntu 22.04, Postgresql 14, postgis :
POSTGIS="3.2.2 628da50" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0" PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY

Comment: use ST_SetSRID https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/185202/276

Comment: I dont need to use set srid because the geom has this srid. Also the error that i got, mentionned it.

Comment: But when I try to user ST_Transform(s.geompos, 32647) for example, this works fine.

Comment: This post may be helpful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396058/postgis-st-transform-fails-for-many-srid-on-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts. It looks like your postgis installation is missing GDAL

Comment: Does `select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=26915`find one row?